Please help me with some ideas
I’ve had this plant for 7 months (midwest, IL), and the flower is just not budding. It's very lanky and curves completely to the side. I’m wondering what else I can do for it, it's my first plant ever so I’m just learning. Please tell me what to do to encourage faster growth!!! It's an “autoflower”. Could someone give me a rundown please!


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could you please post a closeup of the leaf at the bottom left of your photo?

@Community For goodness' sake! No, it isn't hard to tell what Jessica is asking.

The term for a "lanky" plant is "leggy". No confusion what you mean here, but if you see anyone describe a plant as leggy, they mean this.

The lankiness is straightforward - the plant is etiolated because it isn't getting as much light as it wants.  It is stretching out looking for sunlight, and falling over from the weight.
Otherwise, the book The Cannabis Encyclopedia: The Definitive Guide to Cultivation & Consumption of Medical Marijuana (2015) by Jorge Cervantes is excellent and will help guide you.  Jorge has made it free online here because he's that kind of guy.  I will pull a few helpful quotes.

Calcium, phosphorus, and potassium uptake increases to promote floral
formation.  When flowering is initiated, organic cannabis gardeners
change to a soluble flowering mix with less nitrogen.  Gardeners that
use chemical salt-based nutrients switch to a "super bloom" formula
with less nitrogen and more calcium, potassium, and phosphorus...The
increase in floral nutrients necessary during flowering, most notably
phosphorus (P) and potassium (K), is gradual rather than immediate.
p.86

The plant needs more phosphorus and potassium for flowering than it does for growth.  There are affordable and effective cannabis 'vegetative growth' and 'flowering growth' fertilizers available to keep it simple.

Autoflowering - ready for harvest 70-80 days after germination]
Autoflowering Feminized - ...ready for harvest 70 to 110 days after
seed germination.
p.50-51

If you know the specific strain you are growing, it will give you a better idea of when to expect flower buds.  But... isn't it already budding?  What are these?


+1 I've tried growing that plant on a south-facing window in southern Europe and it always yielded basically rubbish. My conclusion is it needs an insane amount of light, moderate water and cool temperature - a difficult combo to get by.
